# How to make a query to see who answered who?

Tags: support, questions, answers, data-explorer

How can I write a query if I want to see if user foobar answered any question by user bletchbaz? I've gotten this far, that I can list the questions. But how can I see, for example, if Jon Skeet answered any of my questions?

```
declare @UserId int = ##UserId##;

select
  Posts.ParentId as [Post Link]
  from Posts
  where Posts.ownerUserId = @UserId 
;
```

Comment: A recent question on [meta.se]: [How to check if a specific user has answered any of my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357561)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Jon Skeet did not answer any of your questions (at least not on Stack Overflow). [Here is the necessary SEDE query to check that](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/613151?answererId=22656&askerId=108207).

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
SELECT a.Id AS [Post Link], a.OwnerUserId AS [User Link], q.OwnerUserId AS [User Link]
  FROM posts AS a
  INNER JOIN posts AS q
    ON a.ParentId = q.Id
  WHERE a.OwnerUserId = ##answererId:int##
    AND q.OwnerUserId = ##askerId:int##
```

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning.

Comment: Cool! I could find that Joel Spolsky answered one of my questions http://data.stackexchange.com/ux/query/613151?answererId=182&askerId=7374

Comment: Ah, nice. I'm sure this query can be turned into a 'cross site' one, but I am too lazy right now to do it.